# Mapstructs generates wrong code in the MapperImpl

Tags: java, mapstruct

My mapper looks like,

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class PersonMapper
{
    @Mapping(target = "someModel", source = "someEto")
    @Mapping(target = "someModel.bloodGroup", source = "someOtherEto.bloodGroup")
    @Mapping(target = "someModel.nature", source = "someOtherEto.nature")
    public abstract PersonModel mapPersonCtoToPersonModel(PersonCto personCto);
}
```

Which generates following Impl

```
@Override
public PersonModel mapPersonCtoToPersonModel(PersonCto personCto) {
    if ( personCto == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    PersonModel personModel = new PersonModel();

    personModel.setSomeModel( someOtherEtoToSomeModel( personCto.getSomeOtherEto() ) );
    personModel.setSomeModel( someEtoToSomeModel( personCto.getSomeEto() ) );

    return personModel;
}
```

But, setting someModel twice will replace the model which is already set. Is this the normal behaviour for Mapstruct?
Anything I can do to make this working besides AfterMapping? Because I've sufficiently large and complicatedly nested models and Etos.

Answer (score 0):

You should create mappers for every nested class (code is untested):

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class SomeModelMapper {     
    public abstract SomeModel map(SomeEto someEto);
}

@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, uses = { SomeModelMapper.class })
public abstract class PersonMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "someModel", source = "someEto")
    public abstract PersonModel map(PersonCto personCto);
}
```

Or you can also do it your way, but the first `@Mapping` needs to be removed:

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class PersonMapper {
    // @Mapping(target = "someModel", source = "someEto")
    @Mapping(target = "someModel.bloodGroup", source = "someOtherEto.bloodGroup")
    @Mapping(target = "someModel.nature", source = "someOtherEto.nature")
    public abstract PersonModel mapPersonCtoToPersonModel(PersonCto personCto);
}
```

Comment: But that will increase complexity to whole new level. I mean if there's a solution by just using same _MappingTarget_?

Comment: You could also removing the first `@Mapping` annotation: `@Mapping(target = "someModel", source = "someEto")` in your original code. This should get the job done as well. Reference: http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#controlling-nested-bean-mappings

Comment: An example: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-nested-bean-mappings

Comment: Thank you! But it is not helping. I tried using _uses = { SomeModelMapper.class }_ but it is generating the same Impl, I mentioned in question.

Comment: In that case only fields from _someOtherEto_ will get mapped, and others will be _IGNORED_ as it's our _unmappedTargetPolicy_

Comment: You need to be more precise. Please describe exactly which fields you expect to be mapped and where exactly.